# SSRS parameters disapear when clicking on apply

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, parameters

We are using SSRS (SQL Server 2012) in SharePoint (2013) integrated mode. The report uses 3 parameters, all of them using shared datasets. It appears that if you take longer than 30sec to select a parameter, after selecting the first one, even though you see all 3 parameter values selected, when you hit "Apply" the report doesn't run and all parameter values return to  again.
Some research led me to this link [Time-out values for shared datasets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155782.aspx)
but I'm unable to change the property "Edit Query execution time out" because I can not find it anywhere and I know that it would not have been set at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled across the answer to the above issue that annoyed users for too long. We had to add a few lines of code to the file global.asax on our reporting web server and that fixed the issue for us.

```
<script runat="server">

protected void Application_BeginRequest()  
{
  if(   FormsAuthentication.IsEnabled
     && Context.Request.RequestType == "POST"
     && Context.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"] == "XMLHttpRequest"
    )
  Context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;  
}

</script>
```

Find the whole article here: [SharePoint Authentication Redirect](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2014/04/23/rs-sharepoint-and-forefront-uag-series-part-2-operational-reports/)